# checkbox data-iconpos=right not working properly using JQM-1.3.2 and JQuery-1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

HTML defined:

```
<div id="domestic_locations_list" data-iconpos="right">
</div>
```

using jquery:

```
     {
      locHtmlString += '<input type="checkbox"  id="' + fieldId + '" name="locCheckBox"  value="' + locField.id + '" ' + checked + '/>'
       + '<label for="' + fieldId + '" >'
          + locField.name + '</label>';
       }                  
 $("#domestic_locations_list").empty().append(locHtmlString).trigger('create');
```

it should attach data-iconpos="right" but its not giving proper UI after upgrading to JQuery-1.9.1.js and JQuery-Mobile-1.3.2.js,.css and cordova 2.9.0 from Cordova 2.8.0 and JQM-1.1.1 and jquery-1.7.2

it should work like this:
  http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/checkbox/
  [image: image of screen]
by default it has **icon of search** which i added in  my  project in images folder and when i select it so this **search icon changed into home** 
why this is happening? Before upgrading it was working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was having the same issue.To fix that I just added the class
        `class="ui-btn-right"`.
If you inspect the element(right click on the element you want to put on right in any webkit based browser like chrome) you will notice that by default it's set to left.You need to make it right.

Example:

```
<a href="#blog" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">Blog</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar issues but only with IOS.  I was also getting the "blue house".  The only way I've been able to get the proper checkbox style is to use a previous version of jQuery Mobile's CSS file.  For example, I used jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css instead of 1.3.2.